# QTreeView, QTreeWidget, QTableWidget or QTableView for object data?

Tags: python, widget, pyside

I have a collection of objects and I want to display their data in rows/columns. However I'm not sure which pyside widget to use. There are a few main features I want to implement which I'm assuming may help decide which widget to use. Each row is an object. Which pyside widget should i use and why?

Features wanted:

- Multi row selection
- Sort by column
- Search/filtering

[image]

Comment: How exactly can we help, apart from looking up the documentation for the features you want?

Comment: which widget do i use? I can figure out the rest

Comment: @JokerMartini. Why did you put those specific classes in the title of your question? Presumably you must have done *some* research to arrive at that shortlist.

Answer (score 1):

Use a tree if the data is hierarchical. Your data is clearly not so it's better to use a table.

The `QTableWidget` is slightly easier to implement than the `QTableView` (which also needs a `QTableModel` as backend) but it has less capabilities. I use a `QTableWidget` for simple cases and a `QTableView` when I need to. Reasons for using a `QTableView` can be to improve performance for large tables, or if I want multiple tables looking at the same data.

I think you can not do searching and filtering with a `QTableWidget` so you would have to use a `QTableView`.